# Why don't the graph "Path" functions (e.g. FindHamiltonianCycle[ ]) work when a graph is specified via its adjacency matrix?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I've defined the function, drawGraph, to display a graph as follows:

drawGraph[g_] := GraphPlot[g, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True]

If I specify a graph via its edges, and then ask for a hamiltonian cycle, everything works fine as seen below

[image]

However if I specify a graph via its adjacency matrix, and then ask for a hamiltonian cycle, I'm told that the adjacency matrix is not a graph. However I can display the adjacency matrix as a graph using my drawGraph[] function as seen below.

[image]

Why does the drawGraph function interpret the adjacency matrix as a graph but not the FindHamiltonianCycle function? The same problem exists with all the other Path functions -- ShortestPath, EulerianPath, etc.

Comment: `GraphPlot` is an obsolete function from the time when Mathematica did not have the `Graph` data structure, and there was no alternative but to use explicit but limited representations such as adjacency matrices.  Having a data structure specifically for representing graphs is generally advantageous for programming.  Why wouldn't you just use `Graph`?

Answer (score 1):

After further study of the Mathematica documentation, I now see how to define a 
graph via an adjacency matrix, namely use the AdjacencyGraph[] function as follows:

[image]

When g is defined this way the Hamiltonian cycle function works

[image]

as do all the other graph functions.

The only problem with using the AdjacencyGraph[] function to define the graph is that although the graph is rendered properly, the vertices are not labeled. The only way I could find to label the vertices was to use the GraphPlot[] function.

[image]

The commenter above claimed that GraphPlot[] was obsolete, but obsolete or not, it's still apparently useful.

Comment: `AdjacencyGraph` is not obsolete; `GraphPlot` is. You can use ` AdjacencyGraph[A, VertexLabels->"Name"]` to obtain vertex labels. (`A` is of course the adjacency matrix.)

Comment: I said that `GraphPlot` was obsolete, which it is. I never said that `AdjacencyGraph` was obsolete.  To show labels, use `VertexLabels -> "Name"`. This is shown on the documentation page of `Graph`. If you want the same style as GraphPlot, use `GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram"`

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry for writing AdjacencyGraph when I meant to write GraphPlot. It's been corrected it. And Thanks for the GraphStyle hint.